# SVG exported from Inkscape are rendered with different font

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have opened a pdf with Inkscape and exported it in Plain SVG. However, when I open it in any browser the text is rendered with a different font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `font-family` property in the SVG file might be set to a font that is not installed on the system. In my case it was `DejaVuSans`.

You should open the SVG file in a text editor and replace all `font-family:DejaVuSans` with for example `font-family:Arial`.